# Table Attributes to be merged from Multiple identical polygons in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, overlapping-features

I have an external Dataset containing Cadastral data. When the lot is shared between different landowners, there are multiple overlapping polygons each storing the landownership and other important attributes separately.

Every overlapping polygon has the same properyID - common feature.

I can extract the table bring it to an SQL engine and create the queries manually; merging all the landowners (L1,L2,L3 etc) and linked it back to a dissolved table by ID.

Can anybody recommend an easier way to do it on ArcGIS Desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should have a single feature class that represents the geometries of the parcels and separate non-spatial table or multiple tables that can be joined or related to the parcels feature class. Having multiple feature classes with the duplicate spatial and non-spatial information is a maintenance hell.

You can either create [join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/essentials-of-joining-tables.htm) or [relate](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/about-joining-and-relating-tables.htm) in ArcMap map document or you can load parcels feature class and non-spatial properties tables into a file geodatabase and then use a [relationship class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/relationships/benefits-of-relationship-classes.htm) in the geodatabase.